# celery tasks with long eta (8+ hours) are executed multiple times in a row when eta is reached

Tags: redis, celery, celery-task

I'm creating a task with eta ranging between 3 and 20 hours and when I look at the worker log, for this task, the worker says "`Got task from broker: ...`" every hour after the original task was received until the eta is reached.

I know that this has to do with setting `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': X}` where X is the number in seconds.

So I played with the visibility_timeout and if I set it to anything less than 1 hour then I can see worker getting the same task every X seconds, however when I set the `visibility_timeout` to X being larger than 1 hour then it keeps defaulting to 1h regardless of the time I set.

Does anyone else run into this issue? Is this a know bug?

I'm using Celery 3.0.11 (Chiastic Slide)
with Redis server version 2.4.15

Comment: I just experienced this bug as well, running Celery v.3.0.19 with a Redis server v.2.4.6, but it's happening even with a worker running on the same machine as the Redis server.

Comment: Also observed with. celery==3.0.21 django-celery==3.0.21 Python 2.7.3, Redis server version 2.2.12. .  running on same machine.

Comment: Also experiencing this bug with celery 3.1.17, Redis server 2.8.4, even when both Redis and the workers run on the same machine.

Comment: also experienced this celery==4.3.0, redis==3.2.1, Redis server v=6.0.9, after an hour I have 12 tasks scheduled instead of one. and I'm running this on my local single machine

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Any message consumer using kombu* connected to the same Redis URL
will help restoring unacked messages, so you have to make sure all of them
are configured with the same `visibility_timeout` value.

A common mistake is starting the Flower monitor like this:

```
celery flower -b redis://somewhere
```

instead of like this:

```
celery -A proj flower
```

as the former means the flower instance will not be configured
with the celery configuration, and then be missing `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS` and the `visibility_timeout` setting.

In addition to this you also have to make sure that wall clocks
are in sync using ntp, as described in the original reply below.

- kombu is the messaging library used by Celery.

**Original reply**:

Even though I haven't heard about anything like this, it could be a bug.
I added some print statements to `kombu/transport/redis.py` to check if the visibility_timeout was set correctly, and it is definitely for me.  Testing that it works with values greater than an hour will take more time though (about 2 hours to be exact) so I can report back then.

In the mean time you could verify that you are setting the visiblity_timeout correctly by adding the print statement yourself (e.g. to the restore_visible method in the redis transport)

Note that this feature is using timestamps, so if you have more than one machine it is important that the clocks are pretty much in sync (especially not drifting away by hours).
You should always use ntp on networked servers and sync regularly.

Comment: I instrumented the kombu/transport/redis.py and the visibility_timeout is indeed set correctly. Moving redis server and celery worker to single machine solved the issue. I checked previous machines and they were in sync (e.g., the system time and date on both was the same)

Comment: Updated the answer with new details!