# Celery 4.4 + Redis - long ETA tasks, default_timeout

Tags: django, redis, celery

We are using Celery (celery==4.4.7) along with Redis broker
We have some long ETA tasks with some tasks having ETA of now + 7 days. We were getting issues of the celery tasks being executed multiple times and during debugging we found that the reason is because default_timeout is 1 hour

I looked here:
[celery tasks with long eta (8+ hours) are executed multiple times in a row when eta is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683546/celery-tasks-with-long-eta-8-hours-are-executed-multiple-times-in-a-row-when)

and

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/4.4.0/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#visibility-timeout

We want to increase the default_timeout to 7 days or a bit longer to 8 days.

```
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {"visibility_timeout": 864000}
```

**Are there any negative consequences of doing this?**